# WxWidget deselecting and decoloring buttons do not remove selected boarder

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a grid of buttons, where upon clicked, all adjacent buttons will be colored. Then, on the next click the selected button's data will will move to the clicked button and the colored buttons will be reverted. The problem is that the colored buttons still have a thicker / darker boarder like they are being colored.
In my example provided, I click on frank, than I click on another button and use the if (action == "clear") statement to try to change the colors of the button to normal. The button colors go back to there default color but the boarder is all messed up. Below is example code along with several function I tried to get the buttons back to normal.

```
if (fmod(x + 1, nFieldWidth) != 0) {
    btn[(y)*nFieldWidth + x + 1]->SetBackgroundColour(*wxRED);
    btn[(y)*nFieldWidth + x + 1]->Refresh();
    if (action == "clear") {
        m_list1->AppendString("Clear ");
        //btn[(y)*nFieldWidth + x + 1]->SetBackgroundColour(*wxWHITE);  // Set to your default background color
        btn[(y)*nFieldWidth + x + 1]->SetOwnBackgroundColour(wxNullColour);  // Clear the custom background color
        btn[(y)*nFieldWidth + x + 1]->SetForegroundColour(wxNullColour);  // Set to your default foreground color
        //btn[(y)*nFieldWidth + x + 1]->SetOwnForegroundColour(wxNullColour);  // Clear the custom foreground color
        btn[(y)*nFieldWidth + x + 1]->SetFont(wxNullFont);  // Clear any custom font
        btn[(y)*nFieldWidth + x + 1]->SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_SYSTEM);
        wxBitmap defaultBitmap;  // Empty wxBitmap
        btn[(y)*nFieldWidth + x + 1]->SetBitmapLabel(defaultBitmap);
        btn[(y)*nFieldWidth + x + 1]->SetBitmapCurrent(defaultBitmap);
        btn[(y)*nFieldWidth + x + 1]->Refresh();  // Refresh the entire parent window
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgA9m.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mjCB.png)

Comment: did you try to call SetStyle() with wxBORDER_NONE?

Comment: also - what platform are you on and what is your wxWidgets version?

Comment: It's windows 10 pro and wxWidget is version  3.2.4. Im not sure what SetStyle your referring to. I tried SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_SYSTEM); but that didnt work.

Comment: it is possible that the border style cannot be changed on the fly. You are better off re-creating the button....